# Mac(El Capitan) NPM module.js:471

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

Summary: I installed brew, then did "`brew install node`". Then, I ran "`npm`", which did not work and return following error. I searched online for a lot of solutions, I did delete/clean out node and reinstall, nothing works.

Error log:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
```

Comment: Have you tried installing node using the installer from their website?

Comment: You might want to remove, then reinstall it as well as check that `brew doctor` gives you a clean bill of health. It's odd that `npm` is requiring `npm` as a dependency of itself here.